# Reputation of single day shows details about the day before

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-history

I found that the reputation chart (in the profile / activity section) once clicked on a single column to display reputation change details of a specific day shows instead details about the day before.

In this first screen i clicked 28 July on my profile, where the bar indicate a positive change but the description belows says "There were no net reputation chnages on this day"

[image]

In this second screen I clicked the next day 29 July where the change should be 5 but instead it show 3 activities for a total of +11, data that in fact should be associated to 28 July

[image]

Comment: Maybe a time zone issue? The SO servers are in the US, but you are in Italy...